# Check last modified date is within n seconds

Tags: linux, bash

I need to check the last modified date of all files within a directory to see if the latest file has been modified within some arbitrary period. Eg. 200 seconds.

Here's the twist, it also has to be a one-liner (its a Marathon health check and I can't rely on a file system being there for a script file).

Here's what I have so far:

```
ls -v | tail -n 1 | expr $(date +%s) - $(xargs date +%s -r) | if [ $PREV -gt 100 ]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

The *ls -v* sorts directory contents in "natural order" (the file names are monotonically increasing), so the latest file will be always be the last.
*tail -n 1* gets the last value.

Then *expr $(date +%s) - $(xargs date +%s -r)* subtracts the file's last modified date from now as a unix timestamp.

Next I want to pass the result forward to an if statement and return 0 or 1 depending on comparison with a constant. But I can't work out how to get the pipe output into the if statement.

Note: I'm aware I could have the if check in the previous pipe wrapping the subtraction, but I think that the one-liner is already confusing enough as it is.

Any help appreciated.
Host OS is Linux. Bash shell.

Comment: Here $PREV is a 'variable' I was using to represent the output of the previous pipe.

Comment: As an aside -- http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend. I'd suggest running not just your own code through it, but answers (before accepting them!) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming GNU `find` (a fair assumption, given other GNU tools used in the question):

```
if [[ $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt '-200 seconds' -print -quit) ]]; then
  echo "The newest file is less than 200 seconds old"
else
  echo "The newest file is more than 200 seconds old"
fi
```

On a system with BSD tools (such as MacOS), this might instead be:

```
if [[ $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -200s -print -quit) ]]; then
  echo "The newest file is less than 200 seconds old"
else
  echo "The newest file is more than 200 seconds old"
fi
```

---

Either of the above (as appropriate for the current platform) will have `find` scan the directory until they find a single file less than 200 seconds old; and will stop at that point and print the name of that file. This makes the search considerably more efficient for large directories than having `ls` sort the entire list (or to continue to scan for more files after one has already been found).

Note also the use of `[[ ]]`, which suppresses string-splitting -- with `[ ]`, quotes around `$( )` would be needed to ensure correct behavior with filenames having spaces in their names, or files whose names could be expanded as glob expressions.

Comment: The question says one liner answer

Comment: @bigbounty, so? Add `;`s after the `echo`s, delete the newlines, and this is a one-liner too -- but unlike answers written initially as a one-liner, this is actually *readable* without needing to scroll left-and-right to figure out how it works. Like correctness (*ahem*), comprehensibility is important -- I'd argue critical -- for a public teaching resource, which is what we're building here; and anyhow, the test, which is the actually important part, **is** on one line; it's just the output code (which someone using this will presumably replace with their own logic) that goes beyond.

Comment: Moved to accept this as best answer. Most brief solution with solid readability. Plus I learned a bunch of cool new find flags. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This code works.

```
if [ `expr $(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y $(ls -t | head -n 1))` -gt 100 ];then echo 1;else echo 0;fi
```

How does it work?

ls -t - lists the files based on the time.

head -n 1 - gives first latest file.

date +%s gives time elapsed since epoch.

stat -c %Y - gives modification time since epoch

expr - subtracting present date from modified file date.

**EDIT - 1**

As per Charles advice

`echo $(( $(date +%s) - $(printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0 stat -c '%Y' | sort -g | tail -n 1) > 100 ))`

This is more elegant way of doing.

Comment: [You shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). See [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) for a best-practice mechanism for finding the newest file in a directory.

Comment: ...not that we actually **need** to find the newest file in a directory to answer the OP's question -- that question can be simplified to "are there **any** files in this directory that are less than 200 seconds old?"; if any such file exists, then the newest must be less than 200 seconds old as well.

Comment: Also, this won't work if your newest file has whitespace in its name.

Comment: You'd avoid the `ls`-driven bugs and the expansion-related issues, btw, by writing this as `echo $(( $(date +%s) - $(printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0 stat -c '%Y' | sort -g | tail -n 1) > 100 ))`, since a command substitution inside an arithmetic expansion isn't prone to string-splitting.

Comment: Ok ,I'll add it as an Edit.Thank you

Comment: (Mind you, in very new bash there's no need for `date +%s`, as one can use `printf '%(%s)T\n' -1` to have the same effect without the overhead of running an external command; however, that needs... I think 4.2, or so?).

Comment: Ok ,I have not got updated myself with new bash.Now I will

Comment: `if [ $(( "$(date +%s)" - "$(stat -c %Y "$(ls -t | head -n 1)" )" )) -gt 100 ];then echo 1;else echo 0;fi` is also a version of the first answer that fixes up all the shellcheck warnings except for [SC2012](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2012).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand what you are looking for but you may try below

```
PREV=$(ls -v | tail -n 1 | expr $(date +%s) - $(xargs date +%s -r)) ; if [ $PREV -gt 100 ]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

If you're looking for something else then please give few more hints.
And what's `$PREV` here? You're comparing this with 100 inside `if` but where does `PREV` value come from?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I came up with:

```
ls -v | tail -n 1 | expr $(date +%s) - $(xargs date +%s -r) | if [ $(xargs) -gt 150 ]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

The modification I needed was using command substitution: $(xargs) to get the previous pipe output.

But I like the answer from bigbounty better than my solution as its cleaner. Marking as solved.

Comment: This is going to be very buggy with filenames with spaces in your directory.